# How to add class when appending list items in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an unordered list group with multiple list items.

Each of those list items have a class 'list-group-item'

However, when I append new list items it's appended without a class.

Is it possible to add a class to it?

Comment: Show the code you already have. It's unproductive to talk in such an abstract way.

Comment: It's definitely possible.  Note that if you are doing the appending with javascript you need to set the className property of the element (not "class" which is a reserved word in js).  Show code!

Comment: Please show the code that finds the list and adds an item.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the list items all have 'green' text color from all having the class = 'list-group-item'

If you want to mess with elements with more than one class, Strongly recommend using jQuery addClass() / removeClass() https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

```js
var adder = document.getElementById('adder')
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
adder.addEventListener('click', function(){
var node = document.createElement("li");
node.innerHTML = "bananas"
node.className = 'list-group-item';
list.appendChild( node);
});
```

```css
.list-group-item{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="list-group-item">apples</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">oranges</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">peaches</li>
 </ul>
 
 <button id='adder'> add bananas </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("my-ul");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item 4"));
li.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item")
ul.appendChild(li);
```

```html
<ul id="my-ul">
  <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```